# nuget package 4.5 tries to gather .Net standard dependencies

Tags: visual-studio-2015, dependencies, nuget, .net-4.5, .net-standard

We are currently developing in .Net 4.5.2.
However, when trying to install Automapper (latest version), it brings a lot of .Net Standard dependencies... although it's indicated in the nuspec that there is no dependencies for .Net 4.5

```
 <dependencies>
  <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.5" />
  <group targetFramework=".NETStandard1.1">
    <dependency id="Microsoft.CSharp" version="4.3.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
    <dependency id="System.Diagnostics.Debug" version="4.3.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
    <dependency id="System.Linq" version="4.3.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
    <dependency id="System.Linq.Queryable" version="4.3.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
```

I can in visual studio ignore the dependencies, but I'm afraid of the behavior in my build (TeamCity), and the way that it's handle those dependencies.
Is this behavior normal ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Are these actually added to the `packages.config` file when you go ahead with the install?

Comment: In fact, I don't know because we are using an internal nuget repo, and as the dependencies are not included in the repo, it fails when trying to install the package because of missing dependencies...

Comment: "it fails when trying to install the package because of missing dependencies" Did you mean you failed to install Automapper to .net framework on you build server? How did you install it and what`s the build error?

Comment: It's directly on visual studio 2015, not the build server (for instance). At work we use a specific nuget repositories, where we manually added the automapper package. We are using the .net 4.5.2 frework. When we try to install the package on the project, it fails. Required dependencies are those of .net standard (even if we are not using .net standard)...

Comment: I create a sample package based on your dependencies. Please try install my package from below link: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkHKK8SV6beshi6VjSOrxexDj0aD If it could install correct in your project, the problem should be related to your package. Otherwise, there has any problem in your Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: @Laurent86, What is the version of your nuget package manager? Have you update it to latest version? NuGet full support library from 2.12.

Comment: Do you have found a solution? We are having the same issue.

Comment: Nope, sorry :/ We did not.